# android book page scrolling with transparent background

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make a book page scrolling effect like the picture below.

This is a Standby screen in Acer Liquid.

It shows a transparent layout slidable with many views on it, and the left-bottom corner shows a book page rolling-up effect. The corner rolled is draggable and transparent.

If I slide the views, the corner rolled shows the views' moving with transparent.

That is what I don't know how to do.

I did the corner rolled with a screenshot bitmap. Take a screenshot and roll it up... That's what I did. And that means the corner rolled will be no change if I slide the views.. because it is a picture!

Does anybody know how to do that?

[image: Acer Liquid e - Standby screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source library you can use. https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Comment: Thank you. But it use bitmaps to render a cylinder still. Is there a solution to curl with views?

Comment: draw the view into a bitmap beforehand